# Are there laws prohibiting people from obstructing the view of an unmarked radar?

Tags: traffic, australia

In Australia sometimes on the side of a straight stretch of road you'll see a car park parallel to the road. More often than not, these have radar that is used to catch people speeding.

The other day, my uncle said that there's no law stopping someone from parking in front of one of these unmarked radars because they are apparently done by contractors, not the police, and the contractor can just re-position. (He even joked that you could box them in with two cars.)

But I am wondering, is there any law in Australia about obstructing the view of an unmarked vehicle with radar? Would it be different if it was a police car?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*I'm not a lawyer; I'm not **your** lawyer.*

#### Victoria

The [*Road Safety Act 1986* (Vic) s 73A](http://www5.austlii.edu.au/au/legis/vic/consol_act/rsa1986125/s73a.html) makes the obstruction of the operation of a safety camera or speed detector an offence.

It is likely that the obstruction of a mobile speed camera would fall within this offence.

The law does not restrict the operation of the device to police, and so it may not be relevant whether the car was marked or not.

#### New South Wales

Certainly, the obstruction of an authorised officer is an offense as per the [*Roads Act* 1993 (NSW) s 240](http://www.austlii.edu.au/cgi-bin/sinodisp/au/legis/nsw/consol_act/ra199373/s240.html) and the [*Road Transport Act 2013* (NSW) s 173](http://www.austlii.edu.au/cgi-bin/sinodisp/au/legis/nsw/consol_act/rta2013187/s173.html)

---

Obviously these apply to NSW and Victoria only; I haven't researched the other states yet. It's possible, though not definite, that other states will have similar laws.

It is also likely, though not definite, that people who attempt to obstruct it may be charged with obstruction of traffic in some way, as most states require you to not obstruct the normal passage of traffic unreasonably. (eg [*Road Obstruction (Special Provisions) Act 1979* (NSW) s 4](http://www5.austlii.edu.au/au/legis/nsw/consol_act/ropa1979422/s4.html))

Comment: Wouldn't the police have to prove that you parked your car there with the intention of blocking their radar?

Comment: @cjdennis the offence is obstruction; intent is irrelevant.

Comment: So the police could park their car behind yours and book you for obstruction? That seems unfair!

Comment: The question is not about police, it is specifically about contractors and the fact that they are not police. However, yes, this is theoretically possible. If you have another question, ask it as a question.